# How do we set compression on ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am planning to use ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer to index documents in batches. I did not find any API to set GZIP compression on client-server communication. Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer allows you to pass a org.apache.http.client.HttpClient client to the constructor, as seen [here](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer.html).

So you can enable gzip at HttpClient level (see [here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DecompressingHttpClient.html) for instance, check with the doc of the exact version you use), and then pass along that instance to ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am not quite sure if there should be any specific way to initialize the HttpClient object. Now looking into the SOLR source code to understand the default implementation.